# using if else if statement inside gesture detector in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

why**strong text**y always else statement executes

```dart
return Stack(
  children: [
    GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
            if ((CountryModel.list[index]) == 'assets/images/american.png') {
              Navigator.Push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => detail(CountryModel.list[0])),
              );
            } else {
              Navigator.Push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => detail(CountryModel.list[1])),
              );
            }
          },
    )
  ],
);
```

Comment: because the if is never true? Try to `print(CountryModel.list[index]);` before the if so you can double check it

Comment: can uh plz give me more detail of ur answer em new to flutter

Comment: Can you include more about `CountryModel.list`. Do you have any others tappable widget inside stack ? You can find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I am not aware how Country Model looks like but aren't you comparing a List of Models to a String? Something like this could work depending on your Variables in the model class. CountryModel.list[index].image == ....

Comment: its solved thnks

Comment: If its solved please post the answer for other people

Answer (score 0):

if ((CountryModel.list[index]) == CountryModel.list[0]) {
Navigator. Push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(
builder: (context) => detail(CountryModel.list[0])),
);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).